# Slow browsing through IE on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, internet-explorer, ibm

We've run into strange issue on the freshly installed servers.
H/W: **IBM server X3550 M4 7914**;
OS: **Windows Server 2012 Std**.

Then we try to browse on the servers thru IE, not all sites are opened or it takes too long time to open the page, i.e. very few of them can be opened.

Local FW are disabled.
Servers are in a new subnet and traffic is allowed for it. VLAN is configured properly
Another Windows Server 2012 host is running OK and Internet access works fine, but it is VM running on Hyper-V 2012.
No proxy is used on the network.

At the same time, if one tries to establish telnet session to any site on 80/443 ports - it does work.
Google works as well.

I've tried to configure single Qlogic adapter to check if the issue remains - it does.
Teaming is configured with the means of QLogic, not by built-in functionality.

IE Enhanced Security is disabled.
IE settings were reset, more than once.

Why would certain sites work while others not - Idk.

I also tried to disable ecncapability and restart server - no luck

**netsh int tcp set global ecncapability=disabled**

Any thoughts?

**UPD1**

VMQ is disabled.
Servers are not running Hyper-V.

**UPD2**

Servers were rebuilt from scratch, got a mail a few mins ago.
Issue still remains.
Teaming is now configured with the means of Windows Server 2012.

Comment: What kind of NIC? Is this server also running Hyper-V?

Comment: Try another browser...if it is slow as well, start looking at drivers.  Or test with another nic.  I thought the xSeries onboards were broadcomm not qlogic, so try the onboard if you aren't already.

Comment: @TheCleaner - yes, already tried to use Google Chrome - the same issue, very slow...

Comment: @pauska - QLogic 10Gb PCI Ethernet Adapter x2 in teaming. Drivers version qlgc_dd_nic_qlge-1.0.1.20_windows_32-64

Comment: Test with a single 1Gb link onboard.

Comment: @TheCleaner - already did that, removed teaming and configured single NIC - same issue.

Comment: you tested with a single onboard nic or with a single qlogic 10gb nic?

Comment: @TheCleaner - single QLogic NIC.

Comment: Yeah, I'm saying (3x now :)) to try connecting the server with just the onboard NIC on the server...not the QLogic.  Then test.  It's most likely an issue with your QLogic NIC(s).

Comment: Try to disable VMQ if it's enabled

Comment: @TheCleaner I will give it a shot.

Comment: hm, servers are in datacenter and ob-board nics are not connected, only QLogic, and that's not so fast to get them connected.

Comment: Forgive me for saying this but: So what? How is the ability to browse the internet from the server relevant to whatever role the server is intended to fulfill? Is this a symptom of another, larger problem? Why would you be browsing the internet from your servers? What I'm saying is that it seems like you've put a lot of time and effort into solving a problem that may not be relevant to the server performing it's intended role.

Comment: @joeqwerty - Yeah, agree and what you are saying is absolutely true, but the customer wants to have IE working and sites been opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue fixed, I'd say workaround found.

Installing older (drivers downgrade) ver. of Qlogic drivers worked like a charm.